# Forgotten parental controls password for Fire HD10

Tags: factory-reset

We have forgotton the parental control password for our Amazon Fire HD10.  I entered the incorrect parental controls password more than 5 times but was never given any other options to try to reset.  So I went with the option to deregister the device from our Amazon account.  this was successful however the next step was to re sync the device but to do this I need wifi to be on and to turn on I'm still being asked for the parental control password.  I have also tried to reset to factory default settings on the device but that also seems to require the parental controls password. I don't know what to do next, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Hard reset your Fire HD10

1. Power off
2. Press vol up and power key at the same time for around 5-6 seconds
3. Reset it..

Follow this video if you're stuck somewhere.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayvWAyftosw
Comment if you're still stuck